# Not Reading Data from Bluetooth Health Device (for Android 2.2 and above)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, buffer, inputstream

I am  trying to capture the (data)reading on Android phone from the 'Bluetooth Health Devices'  such as Oximeter, Thermometer, Weighing Scale machine etc.
I am able to connect the device to phone but when it goes to read the data it stuck over there only. 
 I am doing the following steps..(Android 2.2)
First I am creating socket connection

1. `BluetoothSocket Socket.connect();// for socket connection-----done successfully`
2. `BluetoothSocket tmp= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);` //here
       MY_UUID="00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
3. in read thread

   `byte[] buffer = new byte[37];// i think here  I am not getting exact bytes`

   `int bufferBytes = 0, bufferIndex = 0;`

   ```
       Log.e(TAG, "MESSAGE_READ....");
       Communications comms = null;
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       try {
            comms = new Communications();
            Log.e(TAG, "After Communications....");

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error in communicaton....");
       }


       // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
       while (true) {

           Log.e(TAG, "Its coming in while");
           try {

               try {
                   bufferBytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);// the code stuck here its not going down till health device get off(its directly jump to exception after device get off)
               } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "bufferBytes error ====== +e.getMessage());
               }



               //Log.e(TAG, "bufferBytes====== "+bufferBytes);
               while (bufferBytes > bufferIndex) {

                   String[] message = comms.receiveMessage(buffer,
                           bufferIndex, bufferBytes);
                   bufferIndex = Integer.parseInt(message[1]);
                   Log.e(TAG, "bufferIndex====== "+bufferIndex);
                   if (message[0] != null) {

                       /*
                        * Processing message sent by device
                        */
                       StringTokenizer dataInTokens = new StringTokenizer(
                               message[0]);

                       if (dataInTokens.hasMoreTokens() == true) {

                           String token = dataInTokens.nextToken();
                           Log.e(TAG, "token====== "+token);
                           if (token.equals("a")) {

                               int weight = 0;
                               if (dataInTokens.hasMoreTokens() == true) {

                                   weight = Integer.parseInt(dataInTokens
                                           .nextToken());

                                   // Send a message back to the Activity
                                   msg = mHandler
                                           .obtainMessage(ScaleActivity.MESSAGE_READ);
                                   bundle.putInt(ScaleActivity.WEIGHT,
                                           weight);
                                   msg.setData(bundle);
                                   mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                               }
                           } else if (token.equals("b")) {

                               int weight = 0;
                               if (dataInTokens.hasMoreTokens() == true) {

                                   weight = Integer.parseInt(dataInTokens
                                           .nextToken());

                                   // Send a message back to the Activity
                                   msg = mHandler
                                           .obtainMessage(ScaleActivity.MESSAGE_READ);
                                   bundle.putInt(
                                           ScaleActivity.WEIGHT_TO_SAVE,
                                           weight);
                                   msg.setData(bundle);
                                   mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
   ```

And I tried the Android 4.0 HDP Example also.which is available [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothHDP/index.html)
but our heath devices are not comaptible to hdp. so it is also not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am exactly in the same situation. I am able to stablish the connection and create the socket using the SSP profile (UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB). I have verified that the Bluetooth Health device is exposing the SSP service by executing this reflection code (the method to retrieve device exposed UUIDs is hidden in this API level):

```
Class<?> cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
Method method = cl.getMethod("getUuids");
Object retval = method.invoke(myBTDevice);
```

*(retval contains an array of valid UUID device services which you can connect to.)*

I think the problem is that, before trying to read anything, a set of command/s have to be sent to the device, otherwise the read method will hang forever. I have been googling for some days now trying to figure out this hidden protocol but without success. I have also search by the manufacturer name and model but nothing (DigiFox Fingertip pulse oximeter).

My only hope is that, whith the device a custom software running in windows is provided which successfully communicates with the device and is able to read measures. I may need to use some kind of Bluetooth analyzer or packet sniffer to check the data that is sent to the device before reading anything. If I am able to get it working I will post it here.

Regards.